# An equation for any charge distribution in a constant external electric field. Is it correct?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is the equation (torque, $\tau = p \times E$) correct for any kind of charge distribution? (E is an external constant electric field.) If so, why? Will somebody prove it to me? I'm only sure of its validation for a simple electric dipole.

Comment: This torque formula only works for a dipole in a uniform electric field. If you are considering a general charge distribution in a uniform electric field then, this formula will be valid. You can prove this by considering the fact that the torque on all higher poles (quadropoles, octopoles etc.) in a uniform electric field is 0. So, if you break down your charge distribution into monopoles, dipoles, etc.(which I am not saying will be trivial in all cases), the only parts which will generate a torque will be the dipoles.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't know how to calculate those you're referring to.

Comment: Given that you are able to break down your charge distribution as being composed of monopoles, dipoles, quadropoles etc. All you need to do is note that the torque on a monopole is 0, torque on a dipole is $\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{E}$, and the torque on all higher poles is 0. Then total torque on the charge distribution is $\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{E}$. (Breaking into poles: Suppose your charge distribution consists of discrete point charges. If there is a net unbalanced charge then that is the monopole part. $\vec{p} = \sum \vec{r_i}q_i$ and so on. Then calc. torque on each part.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a system of stationary point charges $q_i$, with position vectors $\mathbf{r}_{i}$ in an external electric field, assuming a value $\mathbf{E}_{i}$ at the position of the $i$th charge. The net torque on this system, about the origin of coordinates is:
$$\mathbf{\tau} =  \sum_{i} \mathbf{r}_{i} \times (q_i \mathbf{E}_{i})$$
or
$$\mathbf{\tau} = \sum_{i} q_i\mathbf{r}_{i} \times \mathbf{E}_{i}$$

In general, as the dipole moment of an arbitrary charge distribution is defined as $\mathbf{p} = \sum_{i} q_i \mathbf{r}_{i}$, we see that torque is not always expressible as the cross product of the dipole moment and the electric field.

However, in the special case that the electric field is uniform, or the charges are close enough together that the variation in the electric field can be neglected, the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ can be factored out of the sum (as it contributes the same value to every term), and one gets
$$\mathbf{\tau} = (\sum_{i} q_i \mathbf{r}_{i}) \times \mathbf{E} = \mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{E}$$

Comment: Thanks. And what about a continuous charge distribution? Should I just replace q with dq and use an Integral sign?

Comment: And also, what exactly is the position vector r? I mean how is it measured?

Comment: It's simply a vector from an arbitrary reference point to the position of concern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_%28vector%29.